# How to work around Java's lack of pointers to pointers when working with linked data structures?

Tags: java, c++, algorithms, data-structures, pointers

I've learned from a textbook how to implement binary search trees recursively in Java, and am working on implementing them nonrecursively. I've found a simple and elegant way to implement an insert method in C/C++ by traversing the tree using a pointer of type Node**, but can't find an elegant way to do this in Java.

My C++ code is as follows:

```
class BST {
    class Node {
    public:
        int key;
        int val;
        Node *left = nullptr;
        Node *right = nullptr;
        Node(int k, int v) : key(k), val(v) {}
    };
    Node *root = nullptr;

public:
    void insert(int key, int val);
};

void BST::insert(int k, int v) {
    Node **link = &root;

    while (*link != nullptr && (*link)->key != k) {
        if (k < (*link)->key)
            link = &(*link)->left;
        else if (k > (*link)->key)
            link = &(*link)->right;
    }

    if (*link == nullptr)
        *link = new Node(k, v);
    else
        (*link)->val = v;
}
```

Which I think expresses the idea pretty directly. My first attempt in Java was the following.

```
public class BST {

    private class Node {
        int key;
        int val;
        Node left = null;
        Node right = null;
        Node (int k, int v) {
            key = k; val = v;
        }
    }
    Node root = null;

    void insert(int k, int v) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(k, v);
            return;
        }

        Node node = root;
        while (node.key != k) {
            if (k < node.key) {
                if (node.left == null) {
                    node.left = new Node(k, v);
                    return;
                } else {
                    node = node.left;
                }
            } else {
                if (node.right == null) {
                    node.right = new Node(k, v);
                    return;
                } else {
                    node = node.right;
                }
            }
        }

        node.val = v;
    }
}
```

This seems much less clear to me - it has to deal with lots of different cases separately, and the code for creating new nodes is mingled with the code for traversing the tree, whereas the C++ version goes through two clear stages. Then it occurred to me that I could replicate the C++ version by storing the Node pointers in objects of a Link class:

```
public class BST {

    private class Link {
        Node node = null;
    }

    private class Node {
        int key;
        int val;
        Link left = new Link();
        Link right = new Link();
        Node (int k, int v) {
            key = k; val = v;
        }
    }
    Link root = new Link();

    void insert(int k, int v) {
        Link link = root;
        while (link.node != null && link.node.key != k) {
            if (k < link.node.key)
                link = link.node.left;
            else if (k > link.node.key)
                link = link.node.right;
        }

        if (link.node == null)
            link.node = new Node(k, v);
        else
            link.node.val = v;
    }
}
```

This allows the algorithm to be expressed elegantly, but the overhead of adding an extra layer of indirection to every node of the data structure seems rather a heavy price to pay. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/241035/31260

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean here by "horrible."  If anything, the Java version is actually clearer.

Comment: `but the overhead of adding an extra layer of indirection to every node seems rather a heavy price to pay.` - Why? The C++ version has two levels of indirection, and you think that's elegant.

Comment: @Telastyn there are two levels of indirection in the algorithm, but not in the data structure. In the C++ version each Node points directly to its children, whereas in the Java version each Node points to a Link object, which in turn points to a Node.

Comment: @ben - `Node **link` is very clearly two levels of indirection.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - what I mean is that in the C++ version there are two clear stages - first I'm finding the link I want to do something to, then I'm doing something to that link. The first Java version feels to me like a tangled mess of special cases.

Comment: @Telastyn - yes, I agree that the algorithm uses two levels of indirection. But that's a single Node** that exists temporarily on the stack while the algorithm is running, whereas the Java version requires an extra Link object to be allocated on the heap for every Node of the tree.

Comment: @Ben - So? This is already decidedly inefficient compared to the standard unlinked BST implementation.

Comment: @Telastyn Hush, don't change the question then your answer turns out wrong ;-) I'm pretty sure doubling the number of cache misses is measurable, and "unlinked" (by which I assume you mean in an array, using indices rather than pointers?) implementation are rather obscure: The JDK and the C++ standard library both have "linked" BSTs and no unlinked variant.

Comment: @delnan - hrm. Fair enough. My data structures course never covered the linked version, just the pointer math version under the auspices of memory efficiency.

Comment: honestly the first version is not "horrible", and the proper way to deal with it

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do it nonrecursively? Recursion *is* a way of dealing with these data structures, it seems strange to rule it out then criticise Java for the next option not being quite so good

Comment: @BenAaronson: no particular reason, I just want to be proficient with nonrecursive as well as recursive implementations.

Comment: @BenAaronson a recursive version would have the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're not following good OO principles.

In this case, the one that's probably most applicable is "**Tell, don't ask**": If you want a `Node` to add a child, you should *tell* it to add a child, you shouldn't *ask* it to expose all the relevant information you need then go ahead and add the child for it. Likewise, if (because you're doing an iterative solution), you need to traverse a level down the tree, *tell* the `Node` you want to traverse to the appropriate child, don't *ask* it for everything you need to know to do the calculation yourself.

Consider:

```
private class Node {
    int key;
    int val;
    Node left = null;
    Node right = null;
    Node (int k, int v) {
        key = k; val = v;
    }

   public Node traverseNext(int targetKey) {
       if (key==target) {
           return null;
       }
       return key < target ? left : right;
   }

   public void setChild(int key, int value) {
       if (key == this.key) {
           return;
       }
       if (key < this.key) {
           left = new Node(key, value);
       }
       else {
           right = new Node(key, value);
       }
   }
```

Then a caller wanting to add a child would just have to do:

```
Node node;
Node nextNode = root;

while(nextNode != null) {
    node = next;
    nextNode = node.traverseNext(key);
}

node.setChild(key, value);
```

(Excuse any mistakes, Java isn't my native language)

That's not exactly stellar code because I had to go out of my way to work around the obvious recursive solution. For example, you wouldn't realistically want to expose a method that cheerfully replaces one child with another if asked. But it should give the basic idea.

**Note:** I realise that this doesn't very directly address the issue which caused the difference between those two code samples- the capability that a pointer has which a reference doesn't. But I'm also of the opinion that it's no coincidence that as soon as you solve this problem in a Java-idiomatic way, that difference ceases to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the repetition by creating the new child `Node`s earlier and defaulting them to empty, rather than using `null` to represent an empty `Node`.  The body of your `while` loop might look something like:

```
Node child = node.right;
if (k < node.key)
    child = node.left;
if (child.isEmpty()) {
    child.set(k, v);
    child.left  = new Node();  //Could be done inside set
    child.right = new Node();
    return;
} else {
    node = child;
}
```

This basically preallocates the next level of leaves, but shouldn't be too much overhead.  Another option could be replacing `left` and `right` with a `children[2]`, then you can use the array index to avoid the repetition.

Comment: Interesting suggestions. But of course in Java, unlike in C, storing the child pointers in an array would create extra overhead much like my Link class. (Maybe even more, due to bounds checking?)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want to do in Java.  Java doesn't offer the freedom of C when dealing with pointers.  The only pointers Java has are object references.

Your first attempt is therefore as good as you can do in Java.  You have to distinguish the case of left, right and root insertion.  If creating and initializing the node is complex, you can move the node creation code to a procedure.

Adding a Link object is a clever idea but it complexifies the data structure as you noted.  It also affects all other methods that manipulate or traverse the tree, and that just to make your insert method more elegant.  A bit silly if you think of it.

So the answer is you can't.  This being said, I am sure it is just an exercise, so experiment as you like.  But in real life, before writing your own binary sort tree, make sure no Java collection fills your needs.  And if they don't, check out open source frameworks like Google guava.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Aaronson's answer is much better than either of my attempts, but I think the main reason is the technique he uses to iterate through the tree, using two `Node` pointers instead of one, rather than the more object-orientated style. The whole thing can be inlined, which allows a direct comparison with my version and shows that it is indeed more elegant, cleanly separating the tree traversal from the node creation (even if it does still take twice as much code as the C++ version):

```
void insert(int k, int v) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(k, v);
        return;
    }

    Node node = root;
    Node next = root;

    while (next != null) {
        node = next;
        if (k == node.key) 
            next = null;
        else
            next = k < node.key ? node.left : node.right;
    }

    if (k == node.key)
        node.val = v;
    else if (k < node.key)
        node.left = new Node(k, v);
    else if (k > node.key)
        node.right = new Node(k, v);
}
```

I do take on board Ben's broader points about the value of using OO principles, and clearly the code is improved further by dividing it into separate methods as he has done.